# how to insert varbinary dat into sqlserverce

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I have develop a small asp.net application to store the data into sqlserverce ,How can i set varbinary(max) in sqlserver ce.i have wrote the  code like this

```
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + txtuname.Text + ".sdf";
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=" + filepath);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCeCommand cmdCreate = new SqlCeCommand("CREATE TABLE Mybusinessapp_Pictures (Id int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY, Name nchar(50),Description nvarchar(500),Data varbinary(510),ImageUrl nvarchar(500))", conn);
    cmdCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Table created:");
```

When I try to insert data into this it showing error like

```
The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = varbinary ]
```

What is was the wrong please help me...

Comment: Anybody help me please ....... how to insert the binary image data into sqlserverce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the image data type, varbinary(MAX) is not suported by SQL Server Compact

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response why it is showing Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar error....

Comment: Hi i have change the data type from varbinary to image but this one also showing error like  "The conversion is not supported. [ Type to convert from (if known) = nvarchar, Type to convert to (if known) = image ] please help me.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have solve that my problem..Thank you so much...